# How to calculate the average number of columns across the rows as well as the maximum numbers of columns in a file in unix?

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk

I have a file looks like:

```
1
2 4 5 6 7 19
20
22
24 26 27 
29 30 31 32 34 40 50 56 58
234 235 270 500
1234 1235 1236 1237
2300
```

considering that my real data file is huge. So I want to check what is the maximum number in this data file. Also I want to check on average how many columns exists within rows. as an example in this small example, the maximum number of column is 9 (in 5th row) and on average there is 3.33 column within rows.
Any Suggestion please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NF > m { m = NF } { s += NF } END { printf("Max = %d\nAvg = %g\n", m, s/NR) }' data.in
Max = 9
Avg = 3.33333
```

The `awk` script will keep track of the maximum number of fields (columns) in `m` and the sum of the number of fields in `s`. When reaching the end of the input stream, it will output the stats collected.

The number of fields in the current record (line) is `NF`, and the number of records read so far is `NR`.

The following version will also keep track of the record with the most number of fields:

```
awk 'NF > m { m = NF; r = NR } { s += NF } END { printf("Max = %d (%d)\nAvg = %g\n", m, r, s/NR) }' data.in
Max = 9 (6)
Avg = 3.33333
```

Comment: Awesome! thank you. It works on my real data as well

Answer (score 1):

You could use the "dc" utility for math work:

```
dc -e "
[zsmlksn]sb
[lk1+skzls+ss]sa
[[Max = ]nlmn[(]nlnn[)]n10an[Avg = ]n5klslk/1/n10an]sp
[lpxq]sq
[?z0=qlaxzlm<bcl?x]s?
0ddddsksmsnssd=?
"
```

Which has been shown below towards the working of the above

```
tr '\t-' ' _'  data.in | # dc wants negative numbers to begin with underscores
dc -e "
[
   z sm  # store current num of cols in register "m"
   lk sn # store row num in register "n"
]sb

[
   lk 1 + sk # increment the number of rows
   z ls + ss # add num of cols to running sum of cols
]sa

[
   [Max=]n
   lmn             # put max number of cols on ToS & print it
   [(]n
      lnn          # put row num at which max number of cols are present on ToS & print it
   [)]n
   10an

   [Avg=]n
     5k ls lk /1/n  # accuracy of 5 digits, compute average = sum of cols / total num of cols
   10an

]sp

[
   lpx # print the results by invoking the macro "p"
   q   # quit
]sq

# while loop for reading in lines
[
   ? z 0 =q # quit when no columns found in the current line read in
   lax      # macro "a" does: rows++, sum+=cols
   z lm <b  # update max cols value stored in register "lm" when cols > lm
   c        # clear out the line and read in the next line
   l?x      # read the next line
]s?

# initializations+set the ball rolling:
# register "sk" -> line kount
# register "sm" -> max cols
# register "sn" -> row number corresp. to max cols
# register "ss" -> sum of cols

0
  d  d  d  d
  sk sm sn ss
d=?
"
```

---

### Results

```
Max = 9(6)
Avg = 3.33333
```